# Continue table to the next PDF page, and print text in between

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I dont know if what I am trying to do is even possible, and it might be too much work for something very insignificant.  I have a servlet that creates a PDF.  I am using iText to write to the created pdf, in my pdf I have a dynamic table that can change the size of the document.  I would like to print "**Continued on next page**" at the bottom of the document whenever it needs to go to the next page.  The problem is I will never know where the page break occurs in my document.

I am more than happy to add code to this, if this is possible.  Also, if this isnt clear, feel free to ask questions, thanks.

EDIT:  Probably talking to myself, but The only way that I think this is possible is if there is a method that realizes that a new page has just been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to **apply this snippet** in your pdf generator class:

```
private static final float FOOTER_MARGIN = 15;
private static final float PAGE_MARGIN_LEFT = 36;
private static final float PAGE_MARGIN_RIGHT = 36;
private static final float PAGE_MARGIN_BOTTOM = 36 + FOOTER_MARGIN;
private static final float PAGE_MARGIN_TOP = 36;
private static final Rectangle PAGE_SIZE = PageSize.A4;

//Put this in your generator method
//..
Document document = new Document(PAGE_SIZE, 
         PAGE_MARGIN_LEFT, PAGE_MARGIN_RIGHT, PAGE_MARGIN_BOTTOM, MARGIN_TOP); 
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, OUTPUT_STREAM); 
writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooter()); 
//..

private class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        Phrase footerText = new Phrase("Continued On Next Page");
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(
                writer.getDirectContent(),
                Element.ALIGN_LEFT, footerText,
                PAGE_MARGIN_LEFT, PAGE_MARGIN_BOTTOM - FOOTER_MARGIN, 0);
    }
}
```

FYI, there are bunch of [iText examples](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php), in your case search for *footer*. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make use of setSkipLastFooter(boolean).  This way, it will print the footer row of your table that has the continued text on every page except the last.  You will need to be sure to setFooterRows on the table.

You could also use [PdfPageEventHelper](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.html), which allows you to intercept various page events including end page event. Inside the onEndPage method you can add the "Continued On Next Page" text to the document.